# Проблема с запуском эмулятора в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator

Пытаюсь запустить один из этих эмуляторов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вылезает что то странное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите все неработающие эмуляторы и установите их заново и будет Вам счастье